# Teamcity/c# build doesn't copy my DLL to the bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, build, teamcity

I have a C++ wrapper DLL added to one of my projects, the proect is my "Set as startup" project.

To do this I just right clicked on the project and did "Add exisitng item" and then in the properties I have
Build Action = None
Copy to Output Directory = Copy always

The code in this project does not directly use this dll, it's used in another project that's part of the solution and I cannot add it to the References as it's not a proper .NET dll.

My TeamCity build doesn't include this dll when it builds my project and I don't know why. I changed the build script so that it just copies the dll from a location to the bin folder but that doesn't work, when I run my app I get a run time error "could not find dll" even though I can actually see it in the bin folder.

So I cannot just copy it to the bin folder, I need to tell Team City to include that dll when the project is built, as it does when I compile it from Visual Studio

So my question is how can I tell Team City to include the dll when it complies my project?

I'm using VS2010, .NET 4

Comment: How are you building within TeamCity? If you ask it to use msbuild, it should be fine. What happens if you use msbuild instead of Visual Studio on your machine?

Comment: Hi Jon. I'm not even sure how to use msbuild on my machine instead of Visual Studio

Comment: Well have you done any research on it? A search for "running msbuild" suggests promising hits...